# Hilbert Spaces are Reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I want to show that all Hilbert spaces are reflexive.  I have found the following proof on StackExchange:

[Hilbert Space is reflexive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255877/hilbert-space-is-reflexive)

However, I do not understand it.  Essentially, we want to show that for all $g \in X^{**}$, (X is some Hilbert space) there exists a unique $x \in X$ such that $g(h) = h(x)$ for all $h \in X^*$.  Following the OP's logic, we should apply the Riesz-Fréchet Representation Theorem (RRT) twice:

Pick any $g \in X^{**}$.  Then, since $g$ is bounded on $X^*$, by RRT there exists a unique $f \in X^*$ such that $||g|| = ||f||$, and $g(h) = \langle h,f \rangle$ for all $h \in X^*$.  Now apply RRT to $f$ to get a unique $x \in X$ such that $||f|| = ||x||$ and $f(y) = \langle y,x \rangle$ for all $y \in X$.  It follows that:

$f(x) = \langle x,x\rangle = ||x||^2 = ||f||^2 = \langle f,f \rangle = g(f)$.

We have shown that for any $g \in X^{**}$ that there exist unique $x \in X$, $f \in X^*$ such that $f(x) = g(f)$.  This is not quite what we want.  We want this to hold for a general $h \in X^*$.

According to icurays1, we have basically defined a bijective mapping $T:X^{**} \to X$.  Why is T bijective, and why does this give us that $X$ is reflexive?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Was this same question posted earlier? I have reposted the answer here in any case.*

For any normed linear space, there is a natural map $T:X \to X^{\ast \ast}$ given by
$$
T(x)(f) = f(x) \quad\forall f\in X^{\ast}
$$
One can show that this is a linear isometry.

Reflexivity means that $T$ is surjective.

Now, in the case of a Hilbert space, there is a natural anti-linear isometry
$$
S_1 : H\to H^{\ast}
$$
given by $S_1(y)(x) = \langle x,y\rangle$. The Riesz Representation theorem says that this map is surjective, and hence an isomorphism.

In particular, $H^{\ast}$ is a Hilbert space, and so there is an anti-linear isomorphism
$$
S_2 : H^{\ast} \to H^{\ast\ast}
$$
Now what you need to check is that $T = S_2\circ S_1$

Comment: Thank you.  But, why does the Riesz Representation Theorem say that $S_1$ is surjective?  All of the versions of the RRT that I have read states that there exists a unique vector $x \in X$ such that $f(y) = \langle y,x \rangle$ and $||f|| = ||x||$, provided that $f \in X^*$.  Also, is the map $S_2$ defined in an analogous manner to $S_1$?  That is, does $S_2$ send $h \in X^*$ to $\langle h, f\rangle$ for some fixed $f$ with the appropriate properties?

Comment: The map $S_1$ is surjective because given $f \in H^{*}$, let $x_f$ be such such that $f(y) = \left< y\ , x_f \right> $ for all $y \in H $. Hence, for any $y \in H$, $S_1(x_f) (y) = \left< y\ , x_f \right>= f(y)$ which means $S_1(x_f) = f$, as desired. This is an isomorphism because $||S_1(x_f)|| = ||f||=||x_f||$. The  appropriate properties preserves, because the $H^{*}$ is a Hilbert space with the norm given by $\left< f, g \right>_{H^{*}} = \left< x_g, x_ f \right>$ where $x_f$ and $x_g$ are the vectors provided by Riesz Representation Theorem, which is unique and, hence, well defined.

Comment: @PeanutBuddaI believe there is a mistake in this answer. If $H$ is complex Hilbert space it cannot be isomorphic to its dual, since the map is conjugate linear. This proof works for real Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of mistakes in your recreation of the proof. You have confused the roles of $h$ and $f$.

In the first application of $RRT$, you should have found $f$ such that 
$$ g(h) = \langle h, f \rangle $$
The version you posted makes no sense since the LHS doesn't depend on $h$, yet it is supposed to hold for all $h$.

In the second application of the theorem, you should find $x$ such that $h(x) = \langle h, f \rangle$ for all $h$ in $X^{*}$.

Comment: Ah, yes you are correct.  I have corrected $g(h) = \langle h,f\rangle$.  For your second comment, why should $h(x) = \langle h,f\rangle$ for all $h \in X^*$?