# Riesz Representation Theorem for Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to learn about Hilbert Spaces. In particular, I am trying to make a presentation about Hilbert Spaces, and so I am trying to add interesting information in wherever I can. One theorem that I am including in the presentation is the Riesz Representation Theorem, which states that any Hilbert space can be identified with it's dual (i.e. if $H$ is a Hilbert Space, then
$
H \cong H^*
$
is an isometric isomorphism). What I am trying to learn more about is the **significance and importance** of this result. It seems silly, but I'm not really sure what to say about this since it appears to be an important result.

Thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: If the Hilbert space is complex, this isomorphism is not a linear map, but rather an antilinear map! So, actually, we have a linear isometric isomorphism $\overline{H}\cong H^*$. Knowing exactly how the functionals on a space look like is a very useful thing to know, because many properties of a (topological) vector space are encoded in their dual space.

Answer (score 1):

An immediate consequence of the Riesz Representation Theorem (i.e. the identification $\mathcal H \cong \mathcal H^*$) is that every Hilbert space is a reflexive Banach space.$\color{red}{^1}$

---

*Related Answers/References.*
$\color{red}{1.}$ [Hilbert spaces are reflexive.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255877/hilbert-space-is-reflexive)

Comment: Thanks, connected-subgroup. I should have mentioned that this is a result that is in my course notes. Do you know of any other notable consequences?

Comment: @DClark I guess one notable consequence is that it allows you to construct the adjoint of an operator.